# Как переименовать все файлы в папке в порядке возрастания, по дате их создания?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Есть папка с файлами. Нужно переименовать все файлы в порядке возрастания, по дате их создания. Есть код, но он переименовывает название файлов в зависимость от их размера, что не подходит:

```py
import os

i = 0
path = "/user/files"
for fileName in os.listdir(path):
    myDest = "video_" + str(i) + ".mp4"
    mySource = path + fileName
    myDest = path + myDest
    os.rename(mySource, myDest)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Есть же готовые приложения, типа `renrot` или `pyRename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

fn_pattern = "video_{num:03d}.mp4"

p = Path("/tmp/test")
for i, f in enumerate(sorted(p.glob("*"), key=lambda x: x.stat().st_ctime)):
    # print(f.with_name(fn_pattern.format(num=i)), f.stat().st_ctime)
    f.rename(f.with_name(fn_pattern.format(num=i)))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень помогло.